# Add video in text view (select video from photo library)

Tags: ios

I tried to piece together a variety of writing methods, but I couldn’t successfully generate a video thumbnail, sometimes it shows that the video is damaged. What I want to do is to generate a video thumbnail first, and when I click, he will automatically play

I'm currently stuck on the "Generate thumbnail from video" section, it doesn't work anyway, not sure if there's something wrong with the generation process, or with the video upload itself, but I'm in the gallery, yes Able to preview videos, in simple terms, I just want to clone a function like a memo, which can add videos in text view and text paragraphs

below is code -->

```
extension AddViewController: PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        for result in results {
            
            if result.itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
                
                print("圖片")
                
                result.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { [weak self] (object, error) in
                    
                    if let image = object as? UIImage {
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            
                            // 在此處處理選擇的圖片
                            self?.handleSelectedImage(image)
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            } else if result.itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.movie") {
                
                result.itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.movie", options: nil) { [weak self] (item, error) in
                    
                    if let url = item as? URL {
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            
                            // 在此處處理選擇的影片URL
                            self?.handleSelectedVideoURL(url)
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    func handleSelectedImage(_ image: UIImage) {
        
        let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
        
        attachment.image = image
        
        // 在此處處理選擇的圖片
        let imageSize = image.size
        
        let textFieldPadding = CGFloat(30) // 文本字段的左右缩进
        
        let textFieldWidth = textView.bounds.size.width - (2 * textFieldPadding)
        
        let scale = textFieldWidth / imageSize.width
        
        let scaledSize = CGSize(width: textFieldWidth, height: imageSize.height * scale)
        
        attachment.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: scaledSize)
        
        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
        
        let placeholderText = NSAttributedString(string: " ")
        
        let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)
        
        mutableAttributedString.append(placeholderText)
        
        mutableAttributedString.append(attributedString)
        
        textView.attributedText = mutableAttributedString
        
    }
    
    func handleSelectedVideoURL(_ url: URL) {
        
        // 取得影片縮圖
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
        
        // 設定時間為影片長度的一半
        let duration = asset.duration
        
        let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        
        imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        
        let time = CMTime(seconds: duration.seconds / 2.0, preferredTimescale: 1)
        
        var thumbnailImage: UIImage?
        
        print("最後的停駐點")
        
        do {
            
            let cgImage = try imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
            
            thumbnailImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            
        } catch {
            
            print("Failed to generate thumbnail image: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            
        }
        
        
        
        // 將影片縮圖新增到文字視圖中
        if let thumbnailImage = thumbnailImage {
            
            let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
            
            attachment.image = thumbnailImage
            
            let attributedString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
            
            let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)
            
            mutableAttributedString.append(attributedString)
            
            textView.attributedText = mutableAttributedString
            
            // 點擊播放影片的操作
            textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            
            textView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(playVideo)))
            
        } else {
            
            print("Thumbnail image generation failed.")
            
        }
        
    }
    
    @objc func playVideo() {}
    
}
```